# Using the "built in" dataset object against a Crystal Report with a stored Procedure as source

Tags: vb.net, stored-procedures, dataset

I need to be VERY clear about what I mean here by dataset. This is NOT the dataset object created in code. This is the dataset object you create by right clicking on your vb.net 2010 project name and selecting ADD. Then selecting New Item and from the DATA template, Dataset, and naming it.

Having done that and given it a name, I selected a Procedure from my data connection list and dropped it into the designer window.

What I'd like to see is some sample code for executing the procedure so the dataset has content.

I hope I'm not completely wrong and it is in fact possible to use a procedure as well as a view for one of these datasets, but I've been having a hard time finding any information because all of the hits I get refer to code and not to what I call the dataset file object. If anyone has better language for this kind of search I'd be very interested in seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be simpler than I could have hoped for. I created the dataset file from a view instead of a procedure. I then included the dataset as my fill object when the query object was returned. The query is built on the client side as there are variables that need to be included in the process.